# compress to .epub format in java

Tags: java, compression, zip, rename, epub

i have 2 folders(meta-inf,oebpf) and 1 file(mimetype) i wish to convert it to epub format.
I am using java.util.zip.ZipEntry, java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream to compress to .epub  but i am unable to read the files. But whin i compress it using 7zip and rename it i can use it.

my mimetype file only contains "application/epub+zip". but in wiki it says to add some more text  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPub#Open_Container_Format_2.0.1

is there a jar file for compressing to epub? or else is there something i should do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this library : https://github.com/psiegman/epublib

It is specially designed for manipulating epub files.

[image: epublib screenshot]

**Sample code :**

```
// Create new Book
Book book = new Book();

// In metadata, set the title and author
Metadata metadata = book.getMetadata();
metadata.addTitle("Epublib test book 1");
metadata.addAuthor(new Author("Joe", "Tester"));

// Add chapter 1
book.addSection(
     "Chapter 1", //
     getResource("/book1/chapter1.html", "chapter1.html") //
);

// Add chapter N
// ...

// Write the Book as Epub
EpubWriter epubWriter = new EpubWriter();
epubWriter.write(book, new FileOutputStream("my_first_book1.epub"));
```

Source : [Creating an ebook programmatically](https://github.com/psiegman/epublib#creating-an-epub-programmatically)

Comment: So, what is your answer?